# UserDefaultへのデータの保存と取り出し

Tags: swift

3-5行目でデータをjsonStringとしてUserDefaultsに保存しています。この時に正しく保存されていることはprint"アイウエオ"のところで確かめています。画像二枚目に結果を載せました。
そして、８行目以降でそれを取り出そうとしています。
しかし取り出そうとした結果"Data not found in UserDefaults"となってしまいました。

#### 試したこと

ChatGPTにこのようになる可能性について聞き、確かめました。forKeyが二つで異なっている可能性や、保存しているデータが多すぎる可能性、保存したあとremoveされている可能性を指摘されましたが、forKeyはコピペした上で確認しておりますし、データはこれだけなので多すぎるはずはなく、またこの二つの処理は連続して行われる(はず？）のためremoveされることもないと思います。

超初心者で、質問の仕方など至らぬ点が多いと思いますがよろしくお願いします。

[image]

[image]

Comment: ソースコード等はキャプチャ画像ではなく、文字のまま質問に貼り付けてみてください。

Comment: teratail で解決済みのようです。 https://teratail.com/questions/lfja9m3tlz55qf